# Not receiving cookie suddenly for HttpWebRequest POST placed through Visual Studio C# code

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, httpwebrequest, getresponse

There is a common framework in our company where we pass username, password, url and get the cookie back. It was working for me for a long time and suddenly it stopped working. My team mates are able to get the cookie successfully with no issues. Here is the common function that we use to get the cookie back. Please help me to complete the troubleshooting

```
public static CookieContainer GetAvidAuthCookies(string url, string userName, string password, bool allowAutoRedirect = false)
{ 
         HttpWebRequest req = null;

         HttpWebResponse resp = null;
        
         CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        req = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
        req.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        //          req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=UTF-8"; //for SOAP
        req.Timeout = 30000;
        req.AllowAutoRedirect = allowAutoRedirect;           
        req.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
        req.Referer = url;
        //req.Host = "api.avidxchange.net";
        req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " +
                                       Convert.ToBase64String(
                                           System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userName + ":" + password));
        var request = Common.GetMemoryStream("username=" + userName + "&password=" + password + "&submit=");

        if (request != null)
        {
            req.ContentLength = request.Length;
            Stream sw = req.GetRequestStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int bytesRead = 0;
            request.Position = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = request.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                sw.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            request.Flush();
            request.Close();
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
        }

        try
        {
            resp = (HttpWebResponse) req.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
            resp = (HttpWebResponse) we.Response;
            Debug.WriteLine("Response:" + we.InnerException + "\r\n" + resp.StatusCode + ":" +
                            new StreamReader(we.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
            var responseStream = we.Response.GetResponseStream();
            if (responseStream != null) responseStream.Position = 0;
        }
        var rStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
        var responseText = new StreamReader(rStream).ReadToEnd();
        var t = resp.Cookies;
        return cookieContainer;
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if my PC has some security settings that are blocking to receive the cookies. If so, please help where to check

Comment: "Suddenly it stopped working." Can you please take a moment and describe what that means? For example, the operation times out, throws an exception, returns a 403 status code, etc.

Comment: req.GetReponse() call is happening. However, responseText is coming empty along resp.Cookies as well. I used to get cookies earlier and able to run subsequent tests using the cookie received many a time. I don't know what happened in the middle as I not am receiving it now

Comment: Are you receiving an [Http StatusCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebresponse.statuscode?view=net-5.0)? Is it 200?

Comment: I am getting StatusCode as Found which means 302 response in HttpWebResponse object

Comment: Think you need to figure out why you're getting a 302 instead of a 200. A 302 status means you're being redirected.

Comment: My other team members are also getting 302 response code but cookie is not empty. Not sure why I am not getting the cookie

Comment: 1) what is .NET version? 2) why you're using ancient `HttpWebRequest`? Check the documentation. 3) is it HTTP or HTTPS request?